# Terminating a worker thread in C++ via a volatile variable

Tags: c++, multithreading

For a worker thread I am using the following "simple" logic

```
void App::RenderThreadFct()
{
    while(m_TerminateRenderThread == false){
        ...
    }
}
```

with `m_TerminateRenderThread` being a volatile variable.
What confuses me a little was digging through the fancy C++ documentation for all the new features for multithreading like `std::future`, `std::promise` and god knows what else.
While all these for sure have their legitimation, they look total overkill to me to tackle such a "simple" problem.
But Internet searches totally confused me as they gave me solely solutions of that kind for doing it "properly" in C++.
Am I missing something and is there any reason why I should not check in a worker thread for a simple termination flag (which of course must be volatile)?

Comment: After the close and to save you more searching -  use `std::atomic<bool> m_TerminateRenderThread;`  See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic

Comment: Oops, yes, now that you point me to it: std::atomic was hiding in plain sight and I did not see it. Thanks!